# Outputting cariables on a casio fx-9750GII

Tags: calculator, basic

Messing around trying to create a simple dice roll program got most of it working but 1 part requires the output of the number rolled I looked up a tutorial and it said that all I had to do was put the variable name followed by a underscore (D_) I’ve tried it but it comes up as a syntax error the programming language the calculator uses is casio BASIC.

Answer (score 1):

Use `locate X,Y,D`, where D is the dice number